# Visual Studio 2015 Community keeps corrupting on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, visual-studio, file-corruption, visual-studio-2015

I have had an issue with my Visual Studio 2015 Community installation. About every second time I start my computer it is no longer working properly. By that I mean the window does not refresh unless I resize it or minimize and maximize it again. Whenever that happens I run the installer in repair mode and that fixes it in about 80% of all cases that happens. If not I run it again and then it has worked every time so far. But after usually 1 to 2 restarts of my computer I get the same odd behavior again.

I have run chkdsk on my harddrive and it not older than a year. It also a SSD.
I have checked my system for malware but I couldn't find anything.
The Windows 10 install is clean. It is not a upgrade from an older Windows version!

I'm running out of ideas on what to do and as you can imagine always having to wait 1 to 2 hours just to do some coding is annoying and not practical.

Comment: This seems similar to what you're describing, it doesn't solve it but it may be interesting https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/823415/visual-studio-window-does-not-refresh-its-content-properly

Comment: Wow. Thank you that was it. Mind to post it as an answer?

Comment: Sure;... but which bit :) The hardware acceleration?

Comment: Mumble is the culprit. I never saw the connection.

Comment: "By that I mean the window does not refresh" - What window exactly?

Comment: @Ramhound The window of Visual Studio. For example when I edit a source file and I scroll the code doesn't visually scroll down unless I resize the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the post https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/823415/visual-studio-window-does-not-refresh-its-content-properly (all below is copied from this site)

- Mumble overlay causes this issue. I had it, added devenv.exe to the blacklist, problem fixed
- Disabling hardware acceleration.
- Starting VS as administrator.
- Reset settings of VS (/resetskippkgs, /resetsettings, /resetuserdata )
- Running VS in safe mode (/safemode)
- Reinstalling VS (including also from new source)
- Creating new user account in windows (this worked for a moment, at third time launching VS2013 this same bug reappeared)
- Reinstalling OS (from new source - burned freshly downloaded .iso)
- Installed VS straight after installing OS (after drivers) and reinstalling it after windows updates (removed before installing updates)